# How do validate iOS/Watchkit App for Appstore submission?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, watchkit

I now, we cannot upload Watchkit Apps to iTunes Connect yet.
But how Do I validate my App today? I want it to be ready as soon as apple accepts watch-app submissions.

Here is the error I got today. Is this a "real" problem?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Based on the discussions in the developer forums, that isn't a "real" error. It's simply because you've included the WatchKit extension. I imagine you'll be able to validate your app once submissions open up, but I haven't seen confirmation of that - or when it will happen.

Answer (score 0):

WatchKit apps and extensions are now validated though the same process as other apps, via submission to the app store.